# How can i group rows using specific criteria that are not in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pipe

One more question on Pandas. I have a dataframe called `df`, one column of which is called `age_year` and contains ages of different people from 20 to 70 years old. I need to group all those ages into 4 groups and visualize later basing on another criteria all those people have in a dataframe. However when i write a function and then try to apply it for my groupby method, it throws an error saying that it is not sure about values of a Series. Is there some other way maybe how I can form criteria for groupping based on some data i already have in a column?

```
def age_group(series):
    if df["age_year"] < 40:
        df["age_young"] = df["age_year"]
    elif df["age_year"] >= 40 & df["age_year"] < 50:
        df["age_40"] = df["age_year"]
    elif df["age_year"] >= 50 & df["age_year"] < 60:
        df["age_50"] = df["age_year"]
    else:
        df["age_60"] = df["age_year"]

df.groupby('age_year').pipe(age_group("age_year"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'age_year': [10, 11, 40, 42, 60 , 62 ,50,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)

df['age_young'] = df.age_year[df['age_year'] < 40]
df['age_40'] = df.age_year[(40 <= df['age_year']) & (df['age_year'] < 50)]
df['age_50'] = df.age_year[(50 <= df['age_year']) & (df['age_year'] < 60)]
df['age_60'] = df.age_year[60 <= df['age_year']]

print(df)
```

**Input:**

```
   age_year
0        10
1        11
2        40
3        42
4        60
5        62
6        50
7        55
```

**Output:**

```
   age_year  age_young  age_40  age_50  age_60
0        10       10.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1        11       11.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2        40        NaN    40.0     NaN     NaN
3        42        NaN    42.0     NaN     NaN
4        60        NaN     NaN     NaN    60.0
5        62        NaN     NaN     NaN    62.0
6        50        NaN     NaN    50.0     NaN
7        55        NaN     NaN    55.0     NaN
```

**Explanation:**

1. `df['age_year'] < 40` returns `bool` type `Series` with value `True` where the condition is met
2. passing this bool-series as index to a column we can filter the values of that column ie `df.age_year[bool-series]`
3. When there are multiple conditions use bit-wise `&` operation on both results ie `(bool-series1) & (bool-series1)`